# Set Mesh origin to match bone orientation

Tags: bones

I want to change armor pieces origins, to match each bone orientation.

I can not set rotation propely. Using cursor snap, does not align to bone, just stays in world orientation.

[image: Cursor Snap]

[image: Origin without any rotation]